# Get Element Text not returning value in xml file

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-parsing, robotframework

My XML file is as below

```
<configuration commit-localtime="2020-09-21 14:53:21 PDT" commit-seconds="1600725201" commit-user="root">
    <comment># End of the data from file (/volume/labtools/lab_cvs/system-test/machine/.global/lab_routes-config)</comment>
    <groups>
        <name>vrrp_ipv4_all</name>
        <interfaces>
            <interface>
                <name>&lt;*&gt;</name>
                <unit>
                    <name>&lt;*&gt;</name>
                    <family>
                        <inet>
                            <address>
                                <name>&lt;*&gt;</name>
                                <vrrp-group>
                                    <name>&lt;*&gt;</name>
                                    <priority>201</priority>
                                    <fast-interval>1000</fast-interval>
                                </vrrp-group>
                            </address>
                        </inet>
                    </family>
                </unit>
            </interface>
        </interfaces>
    </groups>
</configuration>
```

I am using the command as below in robot framework

Get Element Text     ${output}       //priority

but i get the error as

SyntaxError: cannot use absolute path on element

I think i need to use .//priority but i am unable to understand the reason behind this. Since priority is already there in this output why do i need to add [.] to indicate current node?
Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of the [`Get Element Text`](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/XML.html#Get%20Element%20Text) Robotframework  XML library command, the XPath must be relative to the *source* node (`${output}` in your case).  Absolute XPaths are not allowed there.

Comment: So do you mean that i should use relative path and use context nodes? In that case i should change //priority to .//priority to refer to context-node in my specific source code.

Comment: Yes, provided that `${output}` had been previously set to `priority` or one of its ancestors.  (Note that for this Robotframework XML library command, *source* (`${output}`) is the context node for the XPath.)

Comment: Got it. Source is set to ancestor of priority. So i verified with .//priority and it works. Thanks!